# Use Microsoft Exchange Email from Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, exchange-server

I want to use/have an application that works like a mail box or better to say
mail server, I mean I want to have a simple page that is linked to an exchange server in background, receives the needed information like sender, destination, subject, text message and finally the attachment, and then a send button that sends the mail to the destination
by click (off course using the specified exchange server).

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[Send mail using .net](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3096831)

[image]
<sub>(source: [developer.com](http://www.developer.com/img/articles/2003/10/22/ASP/EMail.jpg))</sub>

Comment: thank you so much dear friend,but i want to use this sample application as a pop3 mail server,does your given solution need any additional code or ...??
thank you again

Comment: What I have shown above is a sample code to connect to a server and send email. This cannot  act as pop3 server. Your question asked for a code to send email.

Comment: This code shows how to implement smtp and pop3 clients using c# http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive449.html

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to use MAPI or can it just use SMTP? If it is the former, good luck. No good components out there that I am aware of. If it is the latter, then you can just use the normal `System.Net.Mail` libraries. A finaly option, if you are on Exchange 2007 is to use the web services API, but I'm not familiar with it enough to know if you can actually send mail through it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Imports System.Net.Mail

    Public Sub SendMail()
         Dim msg As New MailMessage("from@stackoverflow.com", "you@stackoverflow.com", "Your Subject Line", "The body of the message")
         Dim client = New SmtpClient("SERVERNAME")
         client.Send(msg)
    End Sub
```